# ios10 and os x10.5.8

Tags: macos, ios, compatibility

my iphone ios10 no longer syncs with iphoto on my old imac which has only been updated to osx10.5.8 (no further auto-upgrades recommended by apple software updater).

I understand it is possible to do a modest OSX software upgrade to the imac with 3rd party software. Can someone describe how to do this, what to use and what OSX version to upgrade to?

imac 7.1
intel core 2 duo
2GHz
3GB memory
(old but still a great internet browser/photo viewer)

Comment: How is a mid 2007 iMac limited to 10.5.8?  You can run El Capitan on it.  You can upgrade the RAM to 6GB and install an SSD.  For under $150 you can have a machine that will be compatible with iOS 10 and last you another couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.4-20-inch-aluminum-specs.html), that machine can update all the way to El Capitan, 10.11 - however, the first step would be to get it to 10.6.8, Snow Leopard, which was the last of the paid upgrades shipped on CD/DVD.

It's still available from [Apple directly](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) [or can often be picked up on eBay for even less]
Once on 10.6.8 you can jump directly to El Capitan through the App Store - in fact it's actually quite difficult to get any intermediate OS. Apple have intentionally left a path to El Capitan open, for machines that cannot run Sierra, which includes your iMac.

You might struggle with some older software needing updates to work properly with such a big jump, but it would allow you to run the latest iTunes & also Photos, the replacement for iPhoto [with a direct cross-grade/conversion within Photos itself] & keep your connection to your phone alive for some time yet.